# How to add custom price for bundle product while add to cart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, bundled-product, custom-prices

I have a bundle product that has been configured as dynamic price is "on". I tried to add custom price while add to cart like following code:

```
$customPrice = 500;
$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Here `$item` is bundle product and configured dynamic price is `"on"`.  The problem is while add to cart, the custom price is ignored if the dynamic price is "on". I found that custom price  ignoring core method. The method is from `"vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/AbstractItem.php"`  class, `"isChildrenCalculated()"` method.

I created plugin for this method, after that the custom price added correctly. But after place the order in the admin `sales_order_view` page the child product prices displaying as zero.
I attached the screen shot of that. Help me to sort out from this issue.

[image]

Comment: is this resolved? did you have the entire code?